# Jquery повороты с условием

Tags: jquery

Нужно чтобы rotate не переваливал за 360deg и при этом чтобы блок не вертелся в обратную сторону...

Пробывал реализовать вот так

```
$('.trub').click(function(){

    var number = true;

    var i = parseInt($(this).attr("data-deg"))+90;
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate("+i+"deg)");

    $(this).css("transition",".5s");

    $(this).attr("data-deg",i);

    // if (i > 270) {
    //          $(this).attr("data-deg","0");
    //   }
    var this1 = $(this);

    if (i == 360) {
        setTimeout(function(this1) {
                $(this1).css('transition', '0');
                $(this1).css("-webkit-transform","rotate(0deg)");


        },1000);
    }
```

i = текущий градус поворота
this = блок который надо повернуть

тут описано - если поворот равен 360 ждем 1 секунду и переопределяем свойства css

А вот не работает( Помогите чем сможете.

Comment: перенесите код из скриншота в текстовый формат

Comment: что за переменная `i`? откуда она берется?

Comment: Это текущий градус поворота блока div(находится выше), Проблема такая, при повороте блока, блок доходит до 360 градусов... и перекручивает в обратную сторону, мне нужно это убрать

Comment: 360*=0* Может в этом дело?

Comment: `this1` не передали, такой синтаксис - `setTimeout(function(this1) {...}, this, 1000);`. Не заметил, вы его объявили, и переобъявили в функции. Вам либо в функции убрать его, либо передавать как я написал

Comment: Artem, попробывал не работает( var this1 = $(this);

   if (i == 360) {
    setTimeout(function(this1) {
          $(this).css('transition', 'unset');
     $(this).css("-webkit-transform","rotate(0deg)");
      
    },this,1000);
   }

Comment: @Ko1ia, тоже ошибся с порядком) оформил ответом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас внутри таймаута this1 будет undefined, тк вы его не передали и переобъявили.

```js
$('.trub').click(function() {

  var number = true;

  var i = parseInt($(this).attr("data-deg")) + 90;
  $(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(" + i + "deg)");

  $(this).css("transition", "0.5s");

  $(this).attr("data-deg", i);

  if (i == 360) {
    setTimeout(function(elm) {
      $(elm).css('transition', 'none');
      $(elm).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(0deg)");
    }, 1000, this);
  }
});
```

```css
.trub {
  background: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trub" data-deg="270"></div>
```

Comment: Так дело в том что мне нужен этот тайм аут для того чтобы этого быстрого вращение в исходное положение не было, как можно реализовать?

Comment: отредактировал, я так думаю логика у вас правильная в примере, так что не особо вникаю как должно работать, ошибка еще была в сбросе transition - none вместо 0

Comment: Спасибо, заработало

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте анимацию удалить так

```
$(this1).css('transition', 'unset');
```